# Adobe Illustrator: how to do a minus globally to make all white areas transparent?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I downloaded a vector from an online stock image library. The vector is of a car that should only have one color, black. Unfortunately, it has some white areas that I need to be transparent. The only color I want on the vector is black. I tried selecting all of the white areas and deleting them but that just makes everything black because the white areas are layered on top of the black areas.

Is there a way for me to tell illustrator to just cut out all of the white areas and everything in the layer below these areas? Basically I want to do a global "minus" of every area that is white.

See image below.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Select all the white objects you wish to use for cutting out the black. In the example below, I held down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting them in the layers panel. You could also do it using the Selection Tool (V) while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, or select one white object and do *Select > Same > Fill colour*
2. Turn the white objects into a compound path using *Object > Compound Path > Make* or use the Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>
3. Select both the black part, and the white compound path
4. Use Minus front in the pathfinder

Example:

[image]

I know you didn't ask this, but another possibility is to use the Shape Builder tool.

1. Select all <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Choose the Shape Builder Tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>
3. While holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> click on the white objects one at a time.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Based on a solution from another post, what I ended up doing was selecting everything, then merge (from Pathfinder), then use magic wand to select all white parts, then hit delete. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

1) Select the direct select tool (A).

2) Select one of the white color objects.

3) Go to Select -> Same -> Fill Color and then delete all white selected objects.